# Define listview in resource file which can be used in different places with same model

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created the following ListView to display data

```
<dataControls:RadListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding StudyResults,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      MinimumHeightRequest="70"
                                      HeightRequest="{Binding Height}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <dataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                            <listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                                <Grid Padding="2,2,2,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout Padding="5,1,1,5" Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Grid >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <maxline:XfMaxLinesLabel MaxLines="2" Text="{Binding BriefTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewLabelStyle}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                            <BoxView Margin="0"
                                                     BackgroundColor="Gray"
                                                     HeightRequest=".25" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ClosestFacility.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <BoxView Margin="0"
                                                     BackgroundColor="Gray"
                                                     HeightRequest=".25" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                        </listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
            </dataControls:RadListView>
```

I want to reuse this exact same ListView + markup in a other screens/view, just with a different ItemsSource it will be bound to same model. I need to use different item source in different screens.

Is there a better way to create some type of resource so I can reuse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lvan's opinion, you can set DataTemplate in ContentPage.Resource or ResourceDictionary, Some code like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Radtemplate">
        <listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
            <listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                <Grid Padding="2,2,2,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,1,1,5" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <maxline:XfMaxLinesLabel MaxLines="2" Text="{Binding BriefTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewLabelStyle}" TextColor="Black"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                            <BoxView Margin="0"
                                                 BackgroundColor="Gray"
                                                 HeightRequest=".25" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ClosestFacility.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewLabelStyle}"/>
                            <BoxView Margin="0"
                                                 BackgroundColor="Gray"
                                                 HeightRequest=".25" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
        </listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->

    <dataControls:RadListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Radtemplate}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding StudyResults,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  MinimumHeightRequest="70"
                                  HeightRequest="{Binding Height}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">

    </dataControls:RadListView>
</StackLayout>
```

About DateTemplate detailed info, you can take a look the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating

**Update:**
Because RadListView is the third party control, I can not install it, so I use ListView as an example, it is the same, you can take a look how to use TapGestureRecognizer.

Please give the Page an x:name=listviewpage firstly, then

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo3.listviewsample.Page2"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Name="listviewpage"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="datatemplate1">
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Margin="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HeightRequest="30" />
                <Label Text="{Binding username}">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.command, Source={x:Reference listviewpage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Email}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource datatemplate1}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding models}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Or you can give ViewCell an x:Name viewcell1 firstly, then:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="datatemplate1">
        <ViewCell x:Name="viewcell">
            <StackLayout Margin="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HeightRequest="30" />
                <Label Text="{Binding username}">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Parent.BindingContext.command, Source={x:Reference viewcell}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Email}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>

 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<model3> models { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand1 command { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        models = new ObservableCollection<model3>()
        {
            new model3(){username="cherry",Email="cherry@outlook.com"},
            new model3(){username="barry",Email="barry@outlook.com"}
        };
        command = new RelayCommand1(obj => method1((string)obj));
        this.BindingContext = this;       
    }

    private void method1(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the email is {0}",str);
    }
}
public class model3
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Command that inherit ICommand:

```
public class RelayCommand1 : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand1(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

When I tap label, it works fine.

Comment: I have added ltemTemplate in resource dictionary, I am able achieve the datatemplate.
But i can't get the image TapGestureRecognizer to work I have added as
````<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.MailTapCommand,
                                                          Source={x:Reference BrowseItemsPage}}"
                                                                              CommandParameter="{Binding ClosestFacility.Email}" />
````

Comment: @ajit, I didn't see where you use TapGestureRecognizer in your code, can you post the update code here?

Comment: I have added tap gesture for the ClosestFacility label above boxview

Comment: @ajit,Please see my update, I use ListView as an example, it is the same as RadListView about DataTemplate, it works fine for TapGestureRecognizer. If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Okke I will give it a try

Comment: @ajit, please give any update if you try my code, thanks.

Comment: I have Problem has been solved by adding binding context


`<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=Parent.BindingContext.CallTapCommand,
                                                          Source={x:Reference telerikviewcell}}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ClosestFacility.Phone, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Comment: @ajit,Glad to hear that your problem solved,please remember to mark the helpful reply as answer,it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `DataTemplate` as resource, that would work.